# How to slice, create a new df and save with a specific name using loop command?

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe is:

```
[Columns Displayed][1]
(3974 rows × 8 columns)
```

If I input `df["Country"].value_counts()`, the output will be resulting in values between 10 to 46. I want to subset only the countries with 46 in the  `value_counts()` result, save each country separately as a new df using "Country Code" to name the df and save this new df using the "Country Code" as PART of the csv file name.

For example, I did manually with Uruguay (Country Code: URY):

```
painel_URY = painel3[painel3.Country =="Uruguay"]
```

Then, I saved it:

```
painel_URY.to_csv(r"C:\pasta1\pasta2\pasta3\painel_URY.csv")
```

What I tried? 
I tried to create a loop using for each and join() but I failed miserably. Im wondering if it is possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` to get the dataframe for each country and save those with 46 rows

```py
for country, group in df.groupby('country'):
    if len(group) == 46:
        group.to_csv(f'./{country}.csv')
```

Comment: Also! Very simple and clean. You made my day. +1